# Widening the domain of a partial function

Tags: isabelle

Apologies for the unprecise title.

I defined a function computing fixed-points like

```
function (domintros) "fix" :: "(env ⇒ env) ⇒ env ⇒ env"
where
  "fix f m n = (if f m n = m n then m n else fix f (f m) n)"
by pat_completeness blast
```

where `type_synonym env = char list ⇀ val` is just a usual (explicit) partial function (map).

I managed to prove termination under certain conditions, but now I want to prove the following lemma, which seems to hold trivially:

```
lemma fix_dom_iter [intro]:
  assumes "fix_dom (f, m, n)"
  shows "fix_dom (f, f m, n)"
oops
```

But only seemingly, since I can't find out how to prove it. There seems to be no `fix.p*` theorem that does what I want.

The hard case is obviously when `~(f m n = m n)`.

Any pointers wrt. how to prove the lemma? Is it even provable?

**Edit:**

I think that `fix.domintros` should rather be an equivalence than an implication. That way, I would be able to prove what I want and it should in fact be sound. Question is, if this is sound for any kind of partial function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately your lemma does not hold. Consider the following variant of your input where I changed the environment to just functions from bool to bool.

```
type_synonym env = "bool ⇒ bool"
function (domintros) "fix" :: "(env ⇒ env) ⇒ env ⇒ env"
where
  "fix f m n = (if f m n = m n then m n else fix f (f m) n)"
by pat_completeness blast
```

I also define a corresponding executable partial function.

```
partial_function (tailrec) "fix2" :: "(env ⇒ env) ⇒ env ⇒ env"
where
  [code]: "fix2 f m n = (if f m n = m n then m n else fix2 f (f m) n)"
```

Now the following witness of `f`, `m`, and `n` show that your statement is not true.

```
definition "f m = (if m True = m False then Not else Not o m)"  
definition "m n = True" 
definition "n = False"
```

`fix_dom (f,m,n)` indeed holds.

```
lemma "fix_dom (f,m,n)" unfolding f_def[abs_def] m_def[abs_def] n_def
  by (auto intro: fix.domintros)
```

But, `fix_dom (f,f m,n)` does not hold as can be observed by a non-terminating computation.

```
value (code) "fix2 f (f m) n"
```